# Cannot display category by "liferay-display.xml"

Tags: liferay-7

I try to create a simple Spring mvc example in liferay 7, and when i add my portlet in liferay-display.xml, but in application menu, my portlet is not display, please help me in this case.
Thanks

[portlet.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sy8r.png)

[liferay-display.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWvM4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove a display-name in the portlet

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>example</portlet-name>
</portlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the portlet setup wizard in the IDE then you would not experience this. How ever if you do it is most important to register the portlet in `portlet.xml`

The `liferay-display.xml` only defines the front end display name and format for the portlet presentation.

I hope this helps!